# My terminal is opening but not gennerating starter code

Tags: gnome-terminal

My terminal was working fine but after doing `npm cache clean --force` it is just opening and not generating anything .the same case with my vs-code terminal.

[image: Ubuntu terminal]

It's just stuck that way with a blinking cursor.

What I tried:

- Recovering ubuntu
- CTRL+C
- CTRL+Z
- Restarting
- Opening new terminal

Comment: Did you make any changes to the default `python3`, particularly version changes (*that will cause  `gnome-terminal` to not work*), or make any changes to one of the startup scripts? (ie. *you may have added a endless loop to them, put in a wait for an event that will never occur etc*)...  ie. I'd try and recall what change(s) you made related to python3/bash more than npm/javascript.

Comment: No i did not make any python3 related changes